# Android - Reading from a txt file and adding to an ArrayList

Tags: java, android

I'm working on Android studio and I'm trying to create a random name generator that retrieves a name from the text file "RandomNames.txt" when a button is clicked. What I get instead is "RandomNames.txt" as the name instead of what's actually in the file. Does anyone have a solution for this? Thanks in advance.

```
private void GenerateRandomName() {
     ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
     Scanner scan = new Scanner("RandomNames.txt");
     while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
         String s = scan.nextLine();
         arr.add(s);


     }
     scan.close();
     Random rand  = new Random();




     username = arr.get(rand.nextInt(arr.size()));



 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner`'s string constructor reads input from the given string. If you want to treat it as a file, you need to use one of the constructors that takes a `File`, `Path` or `InputStream`. E.g.:

```
 Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("RandomNames.txt"));
```

Comment: I tried that and I got a FileNotFoundException, I dragged and dropped the text file into my android studio project, I'm guessing it hasn't registered it somehow. I'll see what I can do.